# Can I turn off IPv6 and just use IPv4 on my iOS device?

Tags: iphone, cellular-data, network

I'm trying to use TeamViewer but have a problem when trying to access the network with IPv6 via GSM.

Can I somehow turn off IPv6 and use only IPv4? I am using an iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 8.3.

Comment: You can use ipv4 to connect if you have the external ip.
You can turn ipv6 off in your router?

Comment: Mr Robot. Thanks :) . I mean turn off on handset itself, as that exact GSM Network proxy don't allow session on IPv6.

Answer (score 9):

1. On a Mac computer, download [Apple Configurator](https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator) from the Mac App 
   Store
2. In Configurator, go to **File > New** Profile (or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>)
3. Fill out the **General** section, then go to **Cellular** and select **Configure**
4. Under **Configured APN Type**, select **Default and Data APNs**
5. Fill out the necessary data using your carrier's APN settings
6. Under **Data APN Supported IP Versions**, select **IPv4**
7. Sign and flash the profile to your phone

Comment: How do you "flash the profile to your phone"?

Comment: Wow this is so awesome. For all those Indian users, who are trying to use JIO sim on iOS 12.1.1 beta , apps stopped working as JIO Is forcing IPv6 and this guy "Steven" saved my life. I started forcing to IPv4 and it works like a charm. 
I was searching this from 2 days and finally ended up on this with some random search keywords

Comment: I hope this works, but maybe I should get an Airtel SIM because it looks like Jio plans to be IPv6 primarily at some point.

Comment: This worked for the phone, but at&t did not want to lease me an IPv4 address.

Comment: How do you "flash the profile to your phone"? 
You connect your device to your mac (e.g. via usb cable) and then you should see the device on the main window of the configurator app, there you can right click and choose add/profile. Then you will need to install the profile on your phone settings.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. Many mobile carriers are deploying and Apple is supporting IPv6 only networking. You may still get an IPv4 address in some cases, but that space is about exhausted in many regions and you’ll want to reach out to team viewer support or your IT professional if you have one for assistance configuring a proper IPv4 to IPv6 gateway or look for a screen sharing solution that’s compatible with this new technology that was proposed in 1992 and became a draft standard in 1998 and defualt standard in 2017.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

In short, IPv6 is designed for mobile in that thousands of devices per person can now have a unique address and this has significant security and performance benefits over IPv4. Turning off IPv6 in 2018 will break many people’s mobile data, but check with your carrier to be sure.  By removing the NAT layer, each device can have the proper firewall and access rules and not all be lumped behind a shared address. It also enables better VPN capabilities if you indeed want to hide the source address and can now have your r served addresses at home and away.

Comment: Sure but for home WiFi it's silly to 'require' it. Not necessary. Worse is depending on how the network is IPv6 connected and if it's default (as for some systems it is) then it could cause delays. For instance some 6rd tunnels are really awful.