# How do I force IPv4 or IPv6 for a Wi-Fi network on iOS 15?

Tags: ios, network, wifi, ipv6

I need to use a sofware that only supports IPv4 on iOS 15, but my ISP provides IPv6 addresses by default.

How do I force my iOS device to use IPv4 only on a certain Wi-Fi network, or the other way around (force IPv6)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an iOS device connects to a WiFi-network, it will by default request both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. If you only see an IPv6 in the settings, it is because your ISP only gives out IPv6 addresses.

If you want to use IPv4 on that WiFi-network, you will need to either get your ISP to change their settings to enable IPv4, or use a VPN service that you can connect to over IPv6 that gives you a virtual IPv4 interface.

It is not possible to disable IPv6 for a specific WiFi-network or for WiFi-networks in general on iOS. Similarly you cannot "force" IPv6.

Comment: My ISP provides both IPv4 and v6 addresses, which I tested on a Mac.
[This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225155/can-i-turn-off-ipv6-and-just-use-ipv4-on-my-ios-device) seems to suggest that it's possible via Apple Configurator, but only shows how to do it for cellular networks. Do you think it's possible to do it for wifi networks via Apple Configurator?

Comment: No, that's just for cellular networks.

Comment: BTW: What kind of software do you need to run that only supports IPv4? - That goes against all Apple recommendations for software developers.

Comment: Thank you. It's a VPN software that only supports IPv4, and I don't think 2 VPN services can be running at the same time on iOS.

Comment: Doesn't your phone get both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address? - Are you sure this VPN software is not having problems due to some completely different cause?